# Laravel Ajax login not set user Auth session

Tags: laravel

I am working in laravel framework. I have two type of login

- Ajax base login
- Simple form submit login

When I submit my simple login form then user login successfully, but when I login user via ajax request then I receive success response of login but when I submit another form after ajax login then it redirect me to simple login page for login because of user Auth not set properly in ajax login.

**Here is middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->route('userLogin');
}
```

**Controller method**

```
public function ajaxPostLogin($inputs) {
    try {
        $inputs = $this->validateInputs($inputs, RulesHelper::$user_login, RulesHelper::$user_login_msg);
        $inputs["user_type"] = 'user';
        $response = $this->getObj(UserHelper::class)->ajaxUserLogin($inputs);
        if (isset($response["success"])) {
            echo json_encode(["success" => true, 'token' => csrf_token()]);
            die;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(["success" => false, 'error' => $response]);
            die;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo json_encode(["success" => false, "message" => $ex->getMessage()]);
        die;
    }
}
```

I don't know that where I am doing mistake. Guide in a right way.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel. After you Authenticate user via AJAX, dont echo any response. Echo only on errors. Not on success. This helped me as well.

Comment: Please provide reasons for this, it seems counterintuitive